# Node/Express app-- how to change connection string (node-postgress) based on localhost vs. remote server

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, node-postgres

I have a node application running an express server that is deployed on heroku. I'm using a postgres database (node-postgres) and currently have the application configured with a connection string for the remote database.

I created a local version of the database, and I would like to configure the application to use a different connection string when running the app on localhost.

I need to somehow detect what server I'm on and then put the conString in an if/else kind of statement. Any ideas or examples? I was having trouble finding the right solution.

Answer (score 3):

For that you should use the standard NodeJS environment variable - `NODE_ENV`.

It should be set to `development` on your local machine. And on your production server it is usually defaulted to `production`, as it is on Heroku: [NODE_ENV=production](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/688)

Then you can access it from your app via `process.env.NODE_ENV`. This will tell you in which environment your app is running, and thus which of the two connections you should use.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [konfig](https://github.com/vngrs/konfig). Create a file named database.js in a folder named config, include it from your app and konfig does the environment switching.

**Example**

config/database.json:

```
{
  "development": {
    "postgresql": {
      "connection_string": "postgres://user:pass@localhost/development"
    }
  },
  "production": {
    "postgresql": {
      "connection_string": "postgres://user:pass@ec2.compute-1.amazonaws.com/sdfk23jf"
    }
  }
}
```

app.js:

```
...
var config = require('konfig')().database.connection_string;
...
```

Use NODE_ENV when you run the server on the command-line, i.e.

```
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

and konfig will automatically do the switching, I think it uses "development" by default.